# "99 bottle of beer on the wall" code not working pure js. if statement and while loop

Tags: javascript, if-statement, while-loop

Hi I have made a 99 bottles of beer song but my code does not seem to be working im not to sure and I cannot figure it out. I really need some help to see where I am going wrong or some one to show my where I am going wrong. I want to if statements or if there is a different way to do it but I need the set-up of how it is im not to sure how to fix it please help.
Thanks in advance.

This is my JavaScript.

```
var bottles = 99
bottle = "bottles";
text = "";

var output = document.getElementById('output');
while (bottles > 0) {

    if (bottles == 1) {
    bottle = "bottle";
    text = "<p>" + bottles + " " + bottle + " of beer on the wall, " + bottles + " " + bottle + " of beer. <br/>";
    bottles--;

        output.innerHTML += text;
    }

    if (bottles == 0) {
    bottles = "no more";
    text += "Take one down and pass it around, " + bottles + " bottles of beer on the wall. </p>"

    output.innerHTML += text;
}

output.innerHTML += "<p> No more bottles of beer on the wall, no more bottles of beer. <br/> Go to the store and buy some more, 99 bottles of beer on the wall.</p>"
```

This is my HTML.

```
<title>My Title</title>
<script src="javascript.js"></script>
<div style="text-align: center;">
 <h1>99 Bottles of Beer Song</h1>

<div id="output"></div>
```

I also have a fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/Matt1990/1wg16qr5/46/

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: Where to start?..... There is no event starting your app. Syntax errors in your variable declaration ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your code is full of errors.**

To debug client-side code like JavaScript you may use the developer tools in Chrome/Firefox by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd>. It shows syntax errors like the one in the variable declaration part.

For further reading see the [Chrome DevTools Overview](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools). Chrome Dev tools are by far better than Firefox/IE/whatever (IMHO)

[image: Chrome Developer tools]

---

Here is the working code. Please compare by yourself.

```js
var bottles = 99,
    bottle = "bottles",
    text = "",
    output = document.getElementById('output');
while (bottles > 0) {
    if (bottles == 1) {
        bottle = "bottle";
    }

    text += bottles + " ";
    text += bottle + " of beer on the wall, ";
    text += bottles + " " + bottle + " of beer.<br>";
    
    bottles--;
    text += "Take one down and pass it around, ";
    text += + bottles + " bottles of beer on the wall.<hr>"

    if (bottles == 0) {
        bottles = "no more";
    }
    output.innerHTML += text;
  text = '';
}

output.innerHTML += " No more bottles of beer on the wall, no more bottles of beer.  Go to the store and buy some more, 99 bottles of beer on the wall.";
```

```html
<div style="text-align: center;">
     <h1>99 Bottles of Beer Song</h1>

    <div id="output"></div>
```

---

Answer (score 2):

### Starting Condition

- We start with 99 bottles
- Since both 99 and 98 are plural, both this round and next round are set to plural

### Iteration

Everytime we start a new round, we need to check if the current (and next) `num` is plural or singular

### Stop Cases

The `while` loop will run until `num = 0`. We have two special cases:

- `num === 1`: this round is singular, next round should be `no bottles of juice`
- `num === 0`: this round is `no bottles of juice`, next round should finish the song with `Go to the store and buy some more, 99 bottles of juice on the wall.` like the original song.

```js
singBottles(15, 'juice');

function singBottles(givenNum, drinkType) {
  let num = givenNum;

  while (num >= 0) {
    const bottlesFirstLine = num === 0 ?
      `no more bottles` :
      `${ num } ${ getPluralState(num) }`;

    const bottlesSecondLine = num - 1 > 0 ?
      `${ num - 1 } ${ getPluralState(num - 1) }` :
      `no more bottles`;

    const firstLine = `${ bottlesFirstLine } of ${ drinkType } on the wall! ${ bottlesFirstLine } of ${ drinkType }!`;

    const secondLine = num - 1 >= 0 ? `Take one down, pass it around... ${ bottlesSecondLine } of ${ drinkType } on the wall!` :
      `Go to the store and buy some more, ${ givenNum } ${ getPluralState(givenNum) } of ${ drinkType } on the wall.`;

    console.log(`${ firstLine }\n${ secondLine }\n`);

    num--;
  }
}

function getPluralState(num) {
  return num === 1 ? 'bottle' : 'bottles';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are syntax errors - and logical errors:

```
var bottles = 99
bottle = "bottles";
text = "";

var output = document.getElementById('output');
while (bottles >= 0) {

    if (bottles == 1) {
         bottle = "bottle";
    }

    // for all > 0
    text = "<p>" + bottles + " " + bottle + " of beer on the wall, " + bottles + 
                           " " + bottle + " of beer. <br/>";

    bottles--;

    if (bottles == 0) {
        bottles = "no more";
        text += "Take one down and pass it around, " + 
                    bottles + " bottles of beer on the wall. </p>"; // ; missing
    } // } missing

    output.innerHTML += text; // needs to be done always!

}

output.innerHTML += "<p> No more bottles of beer on the wall, no more bottles of beer. <br/> Go to the store and buy some more, 99 bottles of beer on the wall.</p>"
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ddbp4hmb/)

Comment: `bottles--;` needs to be moved out of the `if` block

Comment: `bottle` is being defined after it's used. Move `if (bottles == 1){...}` before `text = ...`

Comment: @wumm No. Its define before the loop.

Comment: @AxelAmthor Yes, that's correct. But what's the purpose of that if this way? The variable will never be used again after it's set in this if. The if executes when `bottles` is 1. After the if `bottles` is decremented to 0. The while loop is no longer executed the variable isn't getting used.

Comment: what do i need to move and fix

Answer (score 0):

You missed some parenthesis

```
var bottles = 99; //You need to declare each var like this var x = "x"; var y = "y"
var bottle = "bottles"; // or you can declare it like this var x = "x", y ="y"
var text = "";

var output = document.getElementById('output');
while (bottles > 0) {

    if (bottles == 1) {
    bottle = "bottle";
    }//Missed Parenthesis
    text = "<p>" + bottles + " " + bottle + " of beer on the wall, " + bottles + " " + bottle + " of beer. <br/>";




    if (bottles == 0) {
    bottles = "no more";
    text += "Take one down and pass it around, " + bottles + " bottles of beer on the wall. </p>"
    }
    bottles--;//The decreasment is always at the end
    output.innerHTML += text;
}//Missed parenthesis

output.innerHTML += "<p> No more bottles of beer on the wall, no more bottles of beer. <br/> Go to the store and buy some more, 99 bottles of beer on the wall.</p>"
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1wg16qr5/49/

Answer (score 0):

```
var num = 99;
var bottles = " bottles";
var bottlesWillChange = " bottles"

while (num > 0) {

    if (num === 2) { bottlesWillChange = " bottle"; }
    if (num === 1) { bottles = " bottle"; bottlesWillChange = " bottles"; }

    console.log(num + bottles + " of juice on the wall! " + num + bottles + " of juice! Take one down, pass it around... " + (num - 1) + bottlesWillChange +" of juice on the wall!")

    num--
}
```

Explanation: First we create 3 variables: `num`, `bottles`, `bottlesWillChange`. In the second step we use a while loop with condition `num > 0`. Main part: if num === 2, we change value bottlesWillChange to "bottle", because in a part of our song when bottles equal 2, in last part of this string we should use "bottle". Next if statement work only if, our num === 1, we change first and second values of bottles variable to "bottle", because it's single and `bottlesWillChange` variable value to "bottles".

Comment: @Xcoder, look, first we create 3 variables:`num`, `bottles`, `bottlesWillChange`. In the second step we declarate while loop with condition `num > 0`. 

Main part, `if num === 2`, we change value `bottlesWillChange` to "bottle", because in a part of our song when bottles equal 2, in last part of this string we should use "bottle". Next if statement work only if, our num `=== 1`, we change first and second values of `bottles` variable to "bottle", because it's single and `bottlesWiillchange` variable value to "bottles". I hope it's clear.
[when whe need change var](http://prntscr.com/ln5mru)